# How refactor fetching data from endpoint and again for received data

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have a simple situation, an endpoint for getting UserList which returns basic info for every user and second endpoint for detail info for every user.

My current algorithm for fetching all info is simple, but it isn't optimal.

```
getUsers() {
  this.apiService.getUsers()
    .subscribe((users) => {
      this.users = users;
      this.users.forEach((user) => {
        this.apiService.getUserDetail(user.id)
          .subscribe((details) => {
            user.details = details;
          });
      });
    });
}
```

How can I make it better?

Comment: You may want to post this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not having an endpoint to get the users directly with their details?

Comment: That depends on how and where you want to display the content. Say for example, if you want to show just the list of users without their details right there, it would be better to create a separate route for User Details. On that route, you could send the userId, and then get the details of that particular user with the userId and then display those details there. There are multiple other scenarios and your API should return the data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to ask, what would an ideal UX be for such a list. Ideally, the user should see the list of items with some basic details about each item in the list. And when the user clicks on an item in the list, the user should be navigated to a view with the details of that item from the list.

You API is designed for the same UX. That's why it returns the basic details of the item initially. And then there's another endpoint that you can hit with the id of the item to get the details of that item.

So to show the list of users, you should just return with the list of users from the `getUsers()` method. And when a user is clicked from the list, you can change the view to the User Details view which will have a URL along the lines of `www.your-domain.com/users/1`. `1` here being the `userId`. Now you can get ahold of the userId by injecting `ActivatedRoute` as a dependency in your UserDetailsComponent. From here, you can call your `APIService`'s `getUserDetail` method and pass it the userId that you got. Once you get the user details, you can populated the view with them.

You should always consider lazy loading the data by making ajax calls only when the data is required as opposed to getting all the data at your application load time. This would result in a better user experience.

Comment: In the most cases I have UX like that, for teams, for users and other. But I have one situation where I have to display userList with all details. Maybe it would be good idea to create endpoint which return all info but it is not my API and it is impossible to change anything.

Comment: I have found articles about concatMap and mergeMap operators and I think it is good for that case